# How set targetEntity from config file in symfony?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am building bundle and i wat to use it in another application. I created Entity with user field and i want make config option with user class that must implement AdvancedUserInterface.
In Entity i use this mapping:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface")
 */
private $author;
```

I know i can replace this Interface by adding to config.yml

```
//config.yml

doctrine:
    [...]
    orm:
        [...]
        resolve_target_entities:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface: Draconicka\FosUserBundle\Entity\FosUser
```

But i think this is not good solution. I want put this class to bundle section in config. For examlpe

```
//config.yml
[...]
nattle_demo:
    user_class: Draconicka\FosUserBundle\Entity\FosUser
```

Is this possible? Or better solution is override this bundle and add this field in each application?

Answer (score 0):

I always use resolve taget entities - its easies way to fill targetEntity attr in your bundle.
Sometimes I use setting class in config if I need put class full name (with namespace) in other services. 
For example, you want check user data in authListener. AuthListener has method supportClass ($class) { return $class == '\Your\Configured\Class' }